# *** ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to compare two dicts:

```
> x_state
[{'ID': 1, 'Wert': '6,6743', 'Name': 'Δ'}, {'Wert': 'Δ', 'ID': 3, 'Name': 'Δ'}, {'ID': 4, 'Name': 'D'}, {'ID': 5, 'Name': 'X'}]
> objects
[{'ID': 4, 'Name': 'D'}, {'ID': 5, 'Name': 'X'}, {'ID': 1, 'Wert': '6,6743', 'Name': 'Δ'}, {'Wert': 'Δ', 'ID': 3, 'Name': 'Δ'}]
```

To find differences easier I sort them first and then run some compare-methods over it. As most of the similar problems on SO result in a difference in the length or issues in reading of the file (x_state is a JSON from a file) I decided to count them:

```
unos=[sorted(l, key=itemgetter("ID"))for l in (x_state,objects)]
> unos
[[{'ID': 1, 'Wert': '6,6743', 'Name': 'Δ'}, {'Wert': 'Δ', 'ID': 3, 'Name': 'Δ'}, {'ID': 4, 'Name': 'D'}, {'ID': 5, 'Name': 'X'}], 
 [{'ID': 1, 'Wert': '6,6743', 'Name': 'Δ'}, {'Wert': 'Δ', 'ID': 3, 'Name': 'Δ'}, {'ID': 4, 'Name': 'D'}, {'ID': 5, 'Name': 'X'}]]
#Looks like nothing weird happened

> len(unos)
2
> len(unos[0])
4
> len(unos[1])
4
```

Seems fine, yet from that point everything just fails:

```
> for i,j in unos: print(f"{i}------{j}")
*** ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
> for i,j in zip(unos): print(f"{i}------{j}")
*** ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Trying something else to see whether or not both contain the same data:

```
> any(x != y for x, y in unos)
*** ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

What is going on here? And how would I properly debug this issue?

Comment: In the first iteration `for x, y in unos` tries to do `x, y = unos[0]`. But `unos[0]` has 4 elements, not 2.

Comment: @timgeb - I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. I have only tried this line to assure it is in fact a `zip` and didn't get modified or something

Comment: I am trying to explain the error message to you. You are trying to unpack a list of 4 elements into two variables. This is not possible. `x` and `y` (or `i` and `j`) are two variables. `unos[0]` has 4 elements. These are "too many values to unpack", as the error says.

Comment: `for i,j in zip(unos)` how does it relate to this? Would you mind giving me a solution?

Comment: Did you inspect `list(zip(unos))`?

Comment: @timgeb :`ipdb> list(zip(unos))
*** Error in argument: '(zip(unos))'
`

Comment: [sigh](https://pastebin.com/MGuGcVRv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort command was executed wrongly. Correct:

```
ipdb> !for x,y in zip(sorted(x_state, key=itemgetter("ID")),sorted(objects, key=itemgetter("ID"))): print(x,y)
{'ID': 1, 'Wert': '6,6743', 'Name': 'Δ'} {'ID': 1, 'Wert': '6,6743', 'Name': 'Δ'}
{'Wert': 'Δ', 'ID': 3, 'Name': 'Δ'} {'Wert': 'Δ', 'ID': 3, 'Name': 'Δ'}
{'ID': 4, 'Name': 'D'} {'ID': 4, 'Name': 'D'}
{'ID': 5, 'Name': 'X'} {'ID': 5, 'Name': 'X'}
```